# Can I create a regular windows DLL (for a plugin) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm trying to create a plugin for a program.  The program works by loading your plugin DLL and executing specifically named functions within that DLL.  Pretty standard stuff.  However, I'd like to create my plugin in C# (and I am a bit of newbie).  My question is, can I export regular C like functions from C#? or How do I easily create a stub to do that?

So far Google has not been helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get what I wanted by following a fairly convoluted set of steps:

On the C# side:

1. I created a C# class with an interface
2. made it COM visible,
3. Signed the assembly with a strong name key file
4. Used gacutil to add the assembly to the GAC
5. Registered it with the REGASM tool and produced a tlb type library file.

Then I created an MFC DLL exposing the functions that I needed to export for the plugin interface.  Then using the #import directive in my C++ code to load in the previously mentioned tlb file.  That generates a stub so I can easily call into my C# code from C++ via COM.

The result appears to work perfectly and the performance is instantaneous (this is a bit surprising, I assumed the CLR loading overhead would be noticeable).

Loading the CLR into this particular application isn't really a problem but I am concerned about versioning issues with other plugins.  Is this really a concern when I doing this all through COM?

Comment: if you have a consistent place to keep your dll, and it's not shared by any other application, then you don't need to add it to the GAC. You can instead use the following command line:
regasm /tlb /codebase myDotNetAssembly.dll

Answer (score 1):

No, C# DLLs are managed meaning you need the CLR loaded in order for the computer to understand it. You might be able to use a normal C++ project, add C++/CLI to it (project settings), consume the C# DLL with it, then write basic C exported function that wrap around it.

That would be the first thing that I would try.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create Native DLLs using C# or any .Net framework language. The .Net framework can however use Native DLLs using P/Invoke.

It's not practical writing a native DLL in C# anyway. You'd be better off writing the DLL in C or C++ instead.

If you're going to make the final program in a .Net framework language (Managed C++, C#, .Net), then you can make the DLL in C#, otherwise don't.

Comment: Managed C++ is now known as C++/CLI :)

Comment: Cyril's answer is not technically accurate, since you CAN do this using Visual C++, which interoperates nicely with .NET.

Answer (score 1):

To the op:

I do custom Add-in development for a package that uses old COM interop assemblies.  We wanted to use c#, but since it depends so heavily on late-binding, we have to wind up using vb.net, and build the interfacing class as a COM-interop class.  Once you get over that hurdle, you're usually pretty much golden.  All of the supporting libs outside of the "interface" library are done in C#, so it's less work when the new version of the base application premiere's shortly.

Would love to hear what you are programming Add-ins for, so if there are any tips and/or tricks that we could assist you with, we can do so as you go forward.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Visual C++, you can create a native dll that wraps functionality written in a .NET dll.  If you know C++ at all (or if you are a quick learner), it will be fairly simply to write a C++ shim dll that calls out the functions you implement in a C# assembly.

But, you can't do it using only C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an assembly/dll in C++/CLI that exposes functions in as standard DLL exports.  You could then use these as a proxy for methods in a C# assembly if you want.

However, this doesn't mean it is a good idea.  Forcing the CLR to load into a process is a pretty drastic step, and one that a plug-in author should not force on its host.

For example, Microsoft strongly recommeds that shell extension authors (ie. plug-in code for Windows Explorer) do **not** write those plug-ins (via COM) in .NET, because they don't want the CLR loaded into such a critical applicatoin.

It is possible (though unlikely) that the application will want to load the CLR itself and some point, and if a plug-in has already loaded a given version then this may produce versioning problems.  Also the CLR can not be unloaded from a process, whereas the host application may expect to be able to unload plug-ins.

Comment: All issues have not considered.  I'm looking at loading my C# code using an MFC C++ DLL and the COM interop.