# Export an entry point for a C# dll - is there anything like __declspec(dllexport)?

Tags: c#

I have a C# .dll that interfaces with the API of a large external progam.

That program expects an entry point function in the dll with the form:

```
extern void entrypoint(
char * a,
int * b,
int c);
```

It doesn't find this and complains.

The original/default entry point for my dll is just:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
```

I've tried creating a function like

```
public static void entrypoint(char a, int b, int c)
```

But it's obviously not that simple. I've seen a bunch of stuff about how to do this in C++ with __declspec(dllexport), and I've seen a few complex/hacky solutions for C#, but it seems like there ought to be a straightforward way to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you try to call a method from a c# dll (assembly) from c? If yes, it is not possible (in an easy way, without hosting .net in your c application or com)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/404521

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export c# methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082159/how-to-export-c-sharp-methods)

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, admittedly similar to those questions, but I was hoping something had changed in two years or that there was an elegant way to do it without tons of acronyms and command line utilities and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your external system is COM based, there are ways to do this, as .NET is a COM object under the covers.

Erick

Comment: @TomNysetvold: This "answer" really doesn't say much.  People coming here because the question has an accepted answer may be disappointed.

Comment: Yeah, in the end the external system was throwing an error giving the method name I'd need in a C extension; I found in a sample code that the method name I really needed in a C# extension was something else, and once I fixed that it worked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See my comment. Turned out it looks like it was a COM or .NET system after all. It was just giving me an inappropriate error message, and as soon as I renamed the method to the right thing (found in an obscure sample code) it worked, so really this was the right answer.